# Java.net.SocketTimeoutException in Ksoap2

Tags: android

I am new in android.I am working on android app.
For that  i am calling   web-services using  Ksoap2(2.6) and calling 3  different json services.
 my problem is that when 1 or 2 services coming out of 3 then it is showing java.net.SocketTimeOutException.

Please tell me how to handle the HttptransportSE and TimeOut for avoid SocketTimeoutException.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 13):

The way to fix this is:

```
HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL,60000);
```

Notice the second parameter, which is the timeout value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the soap request.

> At all the optional parameters needs to be replaced with the
>   ZeroLengthSpace.

Comment: This code is not working in my program.Please can you send me code in detail. Thank you in advance.

Comment: is it giving error like `java.net.SocketTimeOutException : Read Timeout`

Comment: yes, same only error I am getting.Like java.net. SocketTimeoutException.

Comment: I am sure...the problem is with your SOAP object you are creating..check twice..you are not making any mistake in passing value of each property properly..

Comment: Hey..., I have checked problem is not with soap object. Some times I am getting response but sometimes it is giving java.net.SocketTimeOutException. So I want to increase the time out,Please tell me how to do this ?